# web farm application issue with compilation

Tags: asp.net, compilation, web-farm

I have an application in a web farm which it consists of 4 web servers.
Every time I made a change on the application and I upload it on the server I am getting an error which said that the *.DLL isn't available.

I upload the DLLs on the master server via ftp and the other servers gets the newer version with replication
. 
It gets compiled on the 1st server and I have to await until it gets compiled on the other servers as well.

Let's say that I have 50 web servers, how could I avoid the compilation on all the servers.

Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide more info regarding how you currently publish your application. You say 'I upload it on the server', what steps do you go through? How is the code/dlls getting to the other nodes to be compiled/copied?

Comment: @Layoric Please have a look on my post. I added more info

Comment: @ StrouMfios Is there any reason why you can't compile the web application locally instead of having to get the web servers to compile it?

Comment: @Layoric I suppose that I follow wrong way to deploy the application. I rebuild the application, I publish the files locally and then I upload them on the server. Is there any other way of deployment?

Comment: That sounds about right, I just didn't understand that from the original question. As far as I can tell no compiling is going on at the servers, just replication. Do you have access to all of the nodes/servers or just the one server you upload to via ftp?

Comment: @Layoric I have access only on the server I upload the files via ftp. Maybe I use wrong term when I am saying 'compile'. When you upload the DLLs on the server, don't you have for the first time a delay? What cause this delay? I thought that this is somehow a compilation.

Comment: This sounds normal for the environment you are working with. I don't think there will be a way around it. You might want to talk to who ever manages the servers for you to get some assistance.

Comment: OK @Layoric. For a meanwhile I thought that everything I knew, was wrong :) I will contact the administrator for more assistance. Thank you very much